# How to focus editable div of UIWebview from uibutton click?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I'm load editable div for UIWebview i want to programatically focus it.

this is my webview content

```
NSString* htmlContentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"<!DOCTYPE html>"
                               "<html>"
                               "<head>"
                               "<script>"
                               "function mysetFocus()"
                               "{"
                               "document.getElementById('content').focus();"
                               "alert('test');"
                               "}"
                               "</script>"
                               "</head>"

                               "<body >"
                               "<div contenteditable='true'  id='content' >TEXT</div>"


                               "<button onclick='mysetFocus()'>Click me</button>"
                               "</body>"

                               "</html>"];

[_webView loadHTMLString:htmlContentString baseURL:nil];
```

if i click 'Click me' button on webview it focus.
but if i call mysetFocus() function like this,

```
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender
{
    [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"mysetFocus()"];
}
```

it not working(alert view coming but focus not working).

How can i programatically focus my editable div.

Comment: Have you read this blog post already: http://stevenpsmith.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/executing-javascript-from-objective-c-in-an-ios-app/

Comment: me also use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` is there any differance.im not using javascript file

Comment: What I meant was this part: "The UIWebView must actually be loaded a view."

Comment: I could not understand it.can you please tell me "what I have to do"

Comment: You can not just declare the webview in your code but also have to add it to your UI. Otherwise WebKit will not execute the JavaScript.

Comment: it not a ui problem.this project working.i cant focus it programatically.

Comment: this is my project file : http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/499493/sampleWebview-zip.html